# Illustration of the Vitaly covering Lemma

Tags: geometry, measure-theory

Consider

> Lemma 1.2 (Vitali's Covering Lemma). Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose (X) is covered by a finite number of open balls, i.e.
> $$
> X \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B_{r_i}\left(x_i\right)
> $$
> for some $N, x_i, r_i$. Then $\exists$ a subset of indices $J \subset\{1, \ldots, N\}$ such that $\left(B_{r_i}\left(x_i\right)\right)_{i \in J}$ are all disjoint, and
> $$
> X \subset \bigcup_{i \in J} B_{3 r_i}\left(x_i\right) .
> $$

I have a proof of this and I understand it. However, visually I can't convince myself that this is true. I tried drawing the following in inkscape
[image]

and then follow the proof. However, the issue is that I did this with inkscape so it is hard for me to get the exact measurements which makes the proof not work.

**Question/Request**: Could someone link me/share a visual application of the Lemma?

Comment: Technically yours isn't a covering, because you've missed a few spots, but be as it may, if you take one ball yes and one no (I advise starting from the right) you'll obtain a collection of disjoint balls that cover the potato if you triple their radii. I managed with 5.

Comment: Although I'm not sure that the solution I've found has anything to do with the one that comes from a proof of the lemma.

Comment: Hi. Could you possibly attach an image so that I get an idea of what this might look like?

Comment: No: I would need to write an answer for that, and I'm not going to.

Comment: I'd suggest you draw it for $\mathbb{R}^1$, that is way simpler to draw and may give enough intuition.